# How to deny the user from selecting the background window in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jframe

I am working with Swing and I am new to it.

When I click a button, new window will open (a `JFrame`), and I want to deny the user from selecting the background window unless and until he closes the new window. New Window should not minimize and maximize also.

How to achieve this?

Comment: And it's "Swing" not "swings" :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use a [modal `JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) instead.

See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)